# Jquery vertical carousel

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Do you know any jquery carousel that doesn't need any extra markup or so...here is my markup:

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li class="navigation-top"><a href="#" class="prev" title="Up"><span></span></a></li>
    <li class="with"><a href="#" title="Shopping">Shopping1</a></li>
    <li class="with"><a href="#" title="Shopping">Shopping2</a></li>
    <li class="with"><a href="#" title="Shopping">Shopping3</a></li>
    <li class="with"><a href="#" title="Shopping">Shopping4</a></li>
    <li class="with"><a href="#" title="Shopping">Shopping5</a></li>
    <li class="with"><a href="#" title="Shopping">Shopping6</a></li>
    <li class="with"><a href="#" title="Shopping">Shopping7</a></li>
    <li class="with"><a href="#" title="Shopping">Shopping8</a></li>

    <li class="with"><a href="#" title="Shopping">Shopping</a></li>
    <li class="with"><a href="#" title="Shopping">Shopping</a></li>
    <li class="with"><a href="#" title="Shopping">Shopping</a></li>
    <li class="with"><a href="#" title="Shopping">Shopping</a></li>
    <li class="with"><a href="#" title="Shopping">Shopping</a></li>
    <li class="with"><a href="#" title="Shopping">Shopping</a></li>
    <li class="with"><a href="#" title="Shopping">Shopping</a></li>
    <li class="with"><a href="#" title="Shopping">Shopping</a></li>
    <li class="navigation-bottom"><a class="next" href="#" title="Up"><span></span></a></li>
</ul><!--[end]  /.navigation-->
```

Comment: What do you consider as "extra markup" exactly?

Answer (score 2):

For example this solution needs only an ID defined on your carousel element:

http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_simple.html

The main page for the above it here for convenience:

http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/

Comment: The vertical sample here: http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_vertical.html

Answer (score 0):

A very light and simple jQuery vertical carousel.

http://paddu.in/labs/jQuery_VerticalCarousel/#